# How to add Giga and SFP ports as LACP trunk members

Tags: switch, trunk, ieee-802.1ax

I want to add 1000M and SFP TX ports as LACP trunk members but am unable to so because the selection is only for ports 1-24. Is there a way to overcome this?  I have a TP-Link TL-SL2428WEB switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the user manual:

> SFP and 1000M port in TL-SL2210WEB/TL-SL2218WEB/TL-SL2428WEB/TL-SL2452WEB, is not able to be the Trunk member. (From Section 5.3.5 Port Trunking, p.57)

Comment: Gotta "love" vendors who are run by marketing people. Thanks for the answer - wasn't in my manual!